# Help with $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x\cdot(1 - 3\sqrt{x})}}\ \text{d}x$ by substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} (1 - 3\sqrt{x})}$$

I tried with the substitution $u = 1-3\sqrt{x}$

I am confused with how to finish this problem I know I am supposed to substitute $u$ and $\text{d}u$ in but I am not sure how to finish it.

Comment: Please format the question and include information on what $u$-substitutions you've tried, and where you got stuck.

Comment: It was really a mess. I edited it trying to format in LaTeX. I need you to tell me if that is the integral you have to solve.

Comment: Yes but only the xs in the denominator should be under radicals

Comment: @K.plum I don't understand. You mean like this? 

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} (1 - 3\sqrt{x})}$$

Comment: Yes sorry I am so bad at this this is my first time on here

Comment: "I tried with the substitution $u = 1-3\sqrt{x}$" Good, and *what did it yield?*

Comment: The integral in the title is currently different from the integral in the text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's set the problem, then you may proceed by yourself.

Performing the substitution

$$u = 1 - 3\sqrt{x} ~~~ \text{and so} ~~~ \sqrt{x} = -\frac{u-1}{3}$$

Hence

$$\text{d}u = -\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}} = -\frac{3}{2}\frac{-3}{u-1}\ \text{d}x$$

$$\text{d}u = \frac{9}{2(u-1)}\ \text{d}x ~~~~~ \to ~~~~~ \text{d}x = \frac{2(u-1)}{9}\ \text{d}u$$

Then your integral becomes

$$\int -\frac{1}{\frac{u-1}{3}u}\frac{2(u-1)}{9} = -\int \frac{2}{3u}\ \text{d}u$$

Now you can proceed for sure.

Comment: Yes that helps a bunch. I think I have it from here and thanks for formatting everything I'll be sure to learn how to do that myself before posting here again

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try $u=\sqrt x$, $du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$

Answer (score -1):

The substitution is a good one.  If $u=1-3x^{1/2}$, then

$$du=\frac12(-3x^{-1/2})dx=-\frac3{2\sqrt x}dx$$

$$-\frac23\int\frac1{1-3\sqrt x}\left(-\frac3{2\sqrt x}dx\right)=-\frac23\int\frac{du}u$$